# Spark Repeatable/Deterministic Results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, partition

I'm running the Spark code below (basically created as a MVE) which does a:

1. Read parquet and limit
2. Partition by
3. Join
4. Filter

I'm struggling to understand why I get a different number of rows in the `joined` dataframe i.e. the dataframe after stage 3 above each time I run the application. Why is this happening?

The reason I think that shouldn't be happening is that the `limit` is deterministic so each time the same rows should be in the partitioned dataframe, albeit in a different order. In the join I am joining on the field that the partition was done on. I am expecting to have every combination of pairs within a partition, but I think this should equate to the same number each time.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val maxRows = args(0)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("epoch_1min").orderBy("epoch")

    val data = spark.read.parquet("srcfile.parquet").limit(maxRows.toInt)
    val partitionDf = data.withColumn("row", row_number().over(windowSpec))
    partitionDf.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    logger.debug(s"${partitionDf.count()} rows in partitioned data")

    val dfOrig = partitionDf.withColumnRenamed("epoch_1min", "epoch_1min_orig").withColumnRenamed("row", "row_orig")
    val dfDest = partitionDf.withColumnRenamed("epoch_1min", "epoch_1min_dest").withColumnRenamed("row", "row_dest")

    val joined = dfOrig.join(dfDest, dfOrig("epoch_1min_orig") === dfDest("epoch_1min_dest"), "inner")
    logger.debug(s"Rows in joined dataframe ${joined.count()}")

    val filtered = joined.filter(col("row_orig") < col("row_dest"))
    logger.debug(s"Rows in filtered dataframe ${filtered.count()}")

  }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think that pretty much covers it. I was thinking the limit is deterministic since I tested just calling `limit(1)` a few times and I got the same result

Comment: The `limit()` in general is definitely not deterministic. Even if you sort the rows beforehand, you could have a case where some rows have the same sorting key (multiple rows with the same "epoch" in your example), and then the tied rows will have the nondeterministic sorting which leads to nondeterministic `limit`. In conclusion the `limit` is only deterministic when the sorting before it is (all rows are sorted consistently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there could be underlying data changes if you start a new App.
2. Otherwise, using Spark SQL just like ANSI SQL on an RDBMS, there is no guaranteed ordering of data when ORDER BY is not used. So, you cannot assume with varying Executor allocation that the processing will be the same (without ordering/sorting) second time around, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about it like that, I guess that is also true. Moreover in Spark it's possible to get different orderings within an application unless you cache intermediate results since the whole pipeline is run at each action